# Why does my Linux-compiled binary not work when I run it on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gtkmm

I have a really easy code using C++ with Gtkmm :

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
Gtk::Window window;
Gtk::Main::run(window);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile this on Linux and It is perfect I can execute it. But the problem is when I copy past the executable I don't achieve to make workable on Windows. But I always think Gtkmm is portable.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the library can be used to build code for different platforms -- that doesn't mean you can copy the executable across platforms.  You still need to build the program for each platform.

Answer (score 5):

Gtkmm is indeed a portable implementation.
Nevertheless you cannot simply copy and paste an executable from Linux to Windows. You have to compile your program once for each platform you're running it on. In your case, you have to create the typical `.exe` executable for Windows.

If you want to cross-compile the executable for Windows (i.e. use your Linux machine to create the `.exe` file for Windows), have a look at the `mingw` compiler toolchain. This [blog](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/) might also have some interesting information for you.

Comment: Thank you but I heard it was not easy at all to compile gtkmm3 with Windows... :/

Comment: It is not, which is why you should get a _pre-compiled_ gtkmm3 to link against when you cross-compile.

Comment: How can I have a pre-compiled gtkmm3 ? :)

Comment: @VickyHarris google is your friemd: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows

Answer (score 1):

It is because executables on Linux and Windows have different structures:
On Linux, you have ELF binaries, which do not work on Windows.
Similarly, if you take an EXE binary from Windows and try to execute it on a Linux machine, it will not work.

See [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and [EXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) for more information.